# Equation and math system on same line

Tags: amsmath, math-operators

To add a math system into a LaTeX document, I add to preambol

```
\newenvironment{sistema}%
{\left\lbrace\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}}%
{\end{array}\right.}
```

then in the document I do something like

```
\[\begin{sistema}
cos(\beta x) \\
sen(\beta x) 
\end{sistema} \]
```

But this time I need to write on a same line

```
f(x)=e^{\alpha x}P(x) + the math system of upper piece of code
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just combine them.  Also use `\cos` and `\sin` to set the trig functions as functions, not variables.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{sistema}%
{\left\lbrace\begin{array}{@{}l@{}}}%
{\end{array}\right.}
\begin{document}
\[
  f(x)=e^{\alpha x}P(x) +
  \begin{sistema}
    \cos(\beta x) \\
    \sin(\beta x) 
  \end{sistema} 
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: since the question is tagged `[amsmath]`, the `cases` environment already exists.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to present the desired effect:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
f(x) = e^{alpha x} P(x) + \begin{cases} \cos(\beta x) \\ \sin(\beta x) \end{cases}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

which yields

[image]